# Argumenst against adding an extra UI element (information icon)

Tags: usability, gui-design

I'm trying to find an argument against adding an extra UI element in one of our form.

We have a URL link and a small "(i)" icon next to it.

Both the URL and the icon can have tooltips.

Something like : (the mockup does not work)  ("link to microsoft" is the text to the external website)

```
link to microsoft (i)
```

I feel that adding an (i) icon is superfluous.

Any better way to do it or arguments against it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no logical argument against the use of icons unless they take up space or increase cognitive load.

However, unless you're linking to a tooltip that provides help or information on the topic, the use of the (i) symbol is wrong *(and here we're dealing with cognitive load)*. If it's just a link to an external website, you should use a link that is more or less recognized as **"open external website**", like the ones on the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, maybe in that context those icons or something similar might better represent the intent. I'll pass the idea to the designer.

Comment: Thanks, I've talked to the designer, we'll keep what we have now, I will this answer at the back of my mind for future references

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "i" in the brackets, literally spell out what you're trying to do.

So intead of

```
link to microsoft (i)
```

do

```
link to microsoft (Opens in new window)
```

The point of good UX is to be clear without adding anything more than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Devin.
You need to use another icon - "open external website" or use a custom one.

Here is an example form Material Design 3.0 - https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%20Outlined%3Aopen_in_new%3A

Also, you can remove the link text and stay only the icon.
Showing tons of characters is not the best user experience.